# Angular - How do I stop an anchor click from happening when someone clicks on a nested button

Tags: angular

I have a div which shows a user notification in my Angular application.

The div is surrounded by an anchor tag which when clicked calls a function that marks the notification as read.

Separately the div contains a button which allows the user to go to the source of the notification.

My question is - when the user clicks on the button, how can I stop the anchor that marks the notification as read to be triggered as well?

```
<a (click)="toggleNotificationRead()" >
    <div>
      <button (click)="goTo()" >
          Go To
      </button>  
    </div>
</a>
```

In my component:

```
goTo() {
  window.location.href = `${this.url}`
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the button's type:

```
<a (click)="toggleNotificationRead()" >
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="goTo()" >
          Go To
      </button>  
    </div>
</a>
```

additionally, you may need to catch the event and stop propagation, but you shouldn't need to do that:

```
<a (click)="toggleNotificationRead()" >
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="goTo($event)" >
          Go To
      </button>  
    </div>
</a>

goTo(event: Event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  window.location.href = `${this.url}`
};
```

as a side note, this HTML isn't valid. You have block-level elements inside of inline elements. I would seriously consider restructuring this code.

Comment: The stopPropogation is what worked.  How would you suggest I rework the html?

Comment: Without knowing what the functional intent is, it's difficult to say. Is the intent to toggle the notification and then to navigate? or are they separate actions the user can take? Are they presented as two separate clickable targets?